# How to trigger increment/decrement on row insertion or deletion?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table of members and a table of articles.

The members can vote on an article. Each individual vote is recorded.

I would like to increment by 1 the article authors vote tally when a vote row is added, and decrement by 1 when the article author's vote tally when a vote row is removed.

How would I do that in MySQL? I know that you can use triggers but how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_ai_article_votes
AFTER INSERT ON article_votes
FOR EACH ROW 
  UPDATE articles
     SET votes = COALESCE(votes, 0) + 1
   WHERE id = NEW.article_id;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_ad_article_votes
AFTER DELETE ON article_votes
FOR EACH ROW 
  UPDATE articles
     SET votes = COALESCE(votes, 0) - 1
   WHERE id = OLD.article_id;
```

*You didn't provide your specific table schema so I improvised with table and column names in my example.*

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34130e/1)** demo

Comment: This is great, but I need to also be able to update two fields in the members table - points and lifetime_points. They would update exactly like you did for the votes field. How do I do that?

Comment: Ok sorry about that. I didn't know. I made sure to accept this answer. Here is the link to the new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522789/how-to-update-multiple-tables-and-fields-in-a-mysql-trigger)

Comment: It's all right. Thanks. You didn't explained what are points and lifetime points. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Well they are just two unsigned integers. They belong to the members table. I would like them to be incremented/decremented in the same trigger as updates the article.votes field. (from your excellent previous example)