# How to update multiple tables and fields in a Trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have the following schema : [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34130e/1).

The trigger is updating the articles.votes field. I also need it to update the members.points field and the members lifetime_points fields with the same formula as updates the articles.votes field. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_ai_article_votes
AFTER INSERT ON article_votes
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  UPDATE articles
     SET votes = COALESCE(votes, 0) + 1
   WHERE id = NEW.article_id;
  UPDATE members
     SET points = COALESCE(points, 0) + 1,
         lifetime_points = COALESCE(lifetime_points, 0) + 1
   WHERE id = NEW.member_id;
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER tg_ad_article_votes
AFTER DELETE ON article_votes
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  UPDATE articles
     SET votes = COALESCE(votes, 0) - 1
   WHERE id = OLD.article_id;
  UPDATE members
     SET points = COALESCE(points, 0) - 1,
         lifetime_points = COALESCE(lifetime_points, 0) - 1
   WHERE id = OLD.member_id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e057f7/1)** demo

Comment: yes it did - I just got to it now - thank you for helping me.